# How to set a Block/Item Texture in Minecraft Forge 1.7.10 Eclipse

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been trying to add textures to my Mod in minecraft forge 1.7.10. I go into src/main/resources/assets/textures/blocks and create a png file with a texture. When I run eclipse and try to find the folder with my textures in it, I am unable to see it. This isn't a coding problem but I been trying for so long but cannot figure it out. If you know how to fix this please help.

Comment: I agree with the VTC, but this has nothing to do with game design and development - the problem lies with Eclipse or Windows, and is off-topic because it has nothing to do with gaming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with gaming.

Answer (score 1):

Is the resources folder set as a Build Source and do you have your mod Build Source at "src/main/java"? That is how mine is set up and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse doesn't actually show these files (to my understanding), but you should be able to still reference the files.

Comment: The OP says Eclipse cannot find the *folder*, though.